# Adding properties to UIViewController and all it's subclasses

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, categories, subclassing

As the title describes I'm looking to add custom properties for every UIViewController and every subclass (like UITableViewController). My first thought was to create a category, but then I realized one cannot add ivars in them, so I can't synthesize the properties. If I simply subclass UIViewController and add stuff there, It wouldn't affect other subclasses.

Basically my purpose with this is to add a custom toolbar to my ´UINavigationController´ subclass (No, I can't use the default for various reasons). It needs to ask each viewController if it wants a toolbar, and - in that case - for an array of toolbarItems. It's kind of like how the UIToolbar works I believe?

How would you do it?

Comment: Why not subclass `UIViewController` and then make all your other subclasses inherit from this new class? How sure are you that the ivars are infact common to all `UIViewController`'s? - it may well turn out that they are not and you end up using `UIViewController` as a bucket to hold everything including the kitchen sink for no reason.

Comment: Because I can't change the, for example ´UITableViewControler's´ superclass. I could subclass each of Apples own UIViewController subclasses though, but that doesn't feel right. I'll update my question concerning the commonness.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding properties (*with* backing storage) is possible using Objective-C's associated object API. I even have a little macro I wrote for the purpose.  But before the macro, here's what it would look like "unrolled":

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UIViewController (SOAdditions)
@property (atomic, readwrite, copy) NSString* myProperty;
@end

static void * const kMyPropertyAssociatedStorageKey = (void*)&kMyPropertyAssociatedStorageKey; 

@implementation UIViewController (SOAdditions)

- (void)setMyProperty:(NSString *)myProperty
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kMyPropertyAssociatedStorageKey, myProperty, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}

- (NSString*)myProperty
{
     return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kMyPropertyAssociatedStorageKey);
}

@end
```

You can find the [documentation for associated storage here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject). You should be aware that there is a performance (speed and memory) penalty for using associated objects.  They're a neat trick, but you might want to ask yourself if there's a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. (The neatest part of the trick, if you ask me, is that the runtime will handle the `-releases` on `-dealloc` for you, according to the policy you specify; See the docs for more info.)

Now here's the macro:

```
#ifndef ASSOCIATED_STORAGE_PROPERTY_IMP
#define THREE_WAY_PASTER_INNER(a, b, c) a ## b ## c
#define THREE_WAY_PASTER(x,y,z) THREE_WAY_PASTER_INNER(x,y,z)

#define ASSOCIATED_STORAGE_PROPERTY_IMP(type, setter, getter, policy) \
static void * const THREE_WAY_PASTER(__ASSOCIATED_STORAGE_KEY_, getter, __LINE__) = (void*)&THREE_WAY_PASTER(__ASSOCIATED_STORAGE_KEY_, getter,__LINE__); \
\
- (type)getter { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, THREE_WAY_PASTER(__ASSOCIATED_STORAGE_KEY_, getter,__LINE__) ); } \
\
- (void)setter: (type)value { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, THREE_WAY_PASTER(__ASSOCIATED_STORAGE_KEY_, getter,__LINE__) , value, policy); } \

#endif
```

If you pop that in your header file, then the above example can be reduced to this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UIViewController (SOAdditions)

@property (atomic, readwrite, copy) NSString* myProperty;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (SOAdditions)

ASSOCIATED_STORAGE_PROPERTY_IMP(NSString*, setMyProperty, myProperty, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY)

@end
```

It should go without saying that the policy (i.e. retain/copy/assign, atomic/nonatomic) you declare in the @property declaration needs to match the policy that you use when using the macro (and/or calling the underlying API, if you're not using the macro) otherwise, you'll end up leaking memory (or crashing.)

Also, I'll say it again for **emphasis**. This trick isn't "free" so please be sure to measure performance and make sure that whatever benefits you're getting by using this are worth it.

EDIT: I'm going to backtrack a bit on my emphatic and dire warnings about the performance penalties of associated object storage. There is a penalty, but a quick investigation tells me that properties implemented this way are not all that much worse than their @synthesized and ivar-backed equivalents. The test is a bit contrived, but with 10,000,000 objects, each with 5 associative-storage-backed iVars, I'm seeing ~30% slower performance setting and getting.  That's really not all that dire, IMHO. I was expecting much worse. The time spent doing the memory management (retains, copies) associated with the set operations is dwarfing the overhead from the associative lookups.

Comment: Am I missing something or is the Macro version harder to read?

Comment: I would think that's subjective. Certainly if one finds it harder to read, one doesn't have to use it.